# Equivalent to C getch() in R

Tags: r

I'm developing a `2048` game in `R` for fun. I used a `scan(n=1)` to user enter him/her move key. But as always in script languages it needs to press `Enter` key to proceed.

Q: Is there any method to make something like `getch` in `C` to apply in `R` to proceed just buy pressing button without pressing `Enter`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using the console, I suggest you to have a look at this: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/getGraphicsEvent.html

Comment: @digEmAll I read the manual you sent! I can say it's good tools. But when I try to install `grDevices` package, it not exists by this: `package ‘grDevices’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)`

Comment: That package should come along with R-base, you don't need to install it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use the windows/x11 graphic environment handlers ([LINK](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/getGraphicsEvent.html)).

Here's an example opening a window where you can move a blue square using your keyboard arrows :

```
keyboardAwareSquare <- function(){
  currPosition <- c(0,0,1,1) 
  drawRect <- function(){
    plot(c(0, 4), c(0, 4), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "",xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
    rect(currPosition[1],currPosition[2],currPosition[3],currPosition[4],col='lightblue')
  }
  keydown <- function(key) {
    offsetX <- 0
    offsetY <- 0
    if(key=='Left') offsetX <- -1
    if(key=='Right') offsetX <- 1
    if(key=='Down') offsetY <- -1
    if(key=='Up') offsetY <- 1
    if(!any(currPosition[c(1,3)] + offsetX < 0) && !any(currPosition[c(1,3)] + offsetX > 4)){
      tmp <- currPosition
      tmp[c(1,3)] <- tmp[c(1,3)] + offsetX
      currPosition <<- tmp
    }
    if(!any(currPosition[c(2,4)] + offsetY < 0) && !any(currPosition[c(2,4)] + offsetY > 4)){
      tmp <- currPosition
      tmp[c(2,4)] <- tmp[c(2,4)] + offsetY
      currPosition <<- tmp
    }
    drawRect()
  }
  drawRect()
  setGraphicsEventHandlers(prompt='use the keyboard arrows to move',onKeybd = keydown)
  eventEnv <- getGraphicsEventEnv()
}

# this part works differntly according to your OS 
if(.Platform$OS.type == 'unix')  x11(type = "Xlib") else x11()

keyboardAwareSquare()
getGraphicsEvent()
```

Comment: in `setGraphicHandler` I encounter this error; `Error in getGraphicsEvent() : no graphics event handlers set`

Comment: Are you using windows,linux or mac ?

Comment: I have replaced windows function with x11, maybe it works now

Comment: Is x11 enable? Can you check it in R looking at the output of `capabilities()` ?

Comment: @digRmAll Yes! It's enabled. and I use it sometimes!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135041/discussion-between-sirsaleh-and-digemall).

Answer (score 0):

Of course @digEmAll guide me in perfect solution for my purpose, Henrik Bengtsson in twitter gave me a solution of exact equivalent to `getch`.
for that we need install `keypress` `cran` package:

`install.packages("keypress")`

then it's ready to use:

`library(keypress)
y = keypress()`

then it waits until first key presses. Best thing about this package is that is supports non character keys like `pagedown`, `up`, `down` and etc.